# What is a good way to organize a PHP website application?

Tags: php, code-organization

When doing large projects my code seems to get all over the place. How do you guys organize your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220347/best-way-to-organize-php-class-heirarchy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434724/organizing-files-of-a-website-powered-by-php-smarty-javascript-mysql

Answer (score 4):

You should be using a [design pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124); consider starting with [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Strictly following a design pattern will improve the readability of your code base immensely (among other benefits).

Comment: MVC ... 2? I wasn't aware there was a second version out ;)

Comment: My bad, MVC Model 2 is a bit Java-specific http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2

Answer (score 3):

Also it is a good idea to use framework (I recommend symfony: http://symfony-project.org). It enforces good files organisation.

Comment: +1 for symfony. Keep in mind it also let's you very easy change the folder structure to your liking using it's extensive configuration files

Answer (score 3):

Cake PHP is another good framework to use which follows MVC

http://cakephp.org/

Comment: I don't think he is asking for a framework, but how to organize PHP code in a project.

Answer (score 3):

I am using below structure and it works fine for me...

```
--> Class  
--> Action  
--> Middle  
--> Js  
--> Css  
--> inc
```

Above is the folder structure i am using.
There will be four files for each file.
One file at root. in which all other files will include and other configuration files also included.

**In Class Folder:**
All the classes for any page will be here.
So  all DB operation will be here.

**In Action File**
All the action and method calling will be here.
When any form post. First it will check for action in this file.
And based on action it will call the function which is in class file.

**In middle File**

All files in this folder will contain the dynamic HTML of the page.
Based on action performed in class files HTML will be displayed from here.

**In JS folder**
All JS related to project will be here.

**In CSS Folder**
All CSS related to your project will be here.

**In INC Folder**
All the common files related to your project will be here.
Like
   conf.php
   sitefunction.php
   constant.php

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/) has a powerful MVC framework.

Comment: +1 Zend Framework, to me it seems it is a lot more powerful and flexible than CakePHP

Answer (score 2):

Here's a page that explains some of php code organization:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

Since I use [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/) to build the web application in all my projects, I just follow the framework's guideline.

To put a support file (css, js, and image files), I usually split it into 2 directory. For a global support files, I put it in public dir:

```
public
 |--> css
 +--> images
 `--> js
```

For a page template, I usually got this from a partner or my client provided it. I will put all the files into `styles/front` and `styles/admin` directory. I'm not changing any arrangement of images, js, and css inside these directory, so I can put any updates directly to it.